# Twitter Bootstrap horizontal form elements on a line

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I want some of my elements to be horizontal on a line but my bootstrap skills are not enough for this.

```
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="create">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="text-center" id="login-tit">Register</h1>
    </div>
    <form id="tab">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="reg-form-left">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" >
        </div><br />
        <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:-22px;">
          <label class="reg-form-left">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" value="" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="reg-form-left">Email</label>
          <input type="text" value="" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="reg-form-left">Password</label>
          <input type="text" value="" placeholder="6 - 20 characters" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="reg-form-left">Password again</label>
          <input type="text" value="" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="reg-form-left control-label">Street/Nr</label>
          <div class="controls-row">
            <div class="controls col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" value="" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="controls col-sm-1">
              <p style="font-size:24px;">/</p>
            </div>
            <div class="controls col-sm-3">
              <input type="text" value="" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
          <label class="reg-form-left">Postal code/City</label>
          <input type="text" value="" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
           <input type="text" value="" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="register-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Create Account</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

I have this form:

[image]

But I want this:

[image]

It would be very nice if someone could help me to achieve what I want.

Comment: Can you post a working [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Forget the fiddle! I can't even tell what you want from your screen shots. Can you add a statement that says what is wrong and exactly where? PS: Fiddles or Plunkers are always good too :)

Comment: I want the form of the bottom image where the input texts of street/Nr are on the same line

Answer (score 0):

You need to know few things first -

- Every time you use floats or similar CSS positioning, it affects the following elements as now the positions for new elements are not defined.
- When ever you use `col-*` attribute it adds default padding to the element. For alignments, you need to wrap your content in `row` first to avoid this issue.

Here's the fix to the final few lines of your code

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="reg-form-left control-label">Street/Nr</label>
  <div class="controls-row">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="controls col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" value="" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="controls col-sm-1">
        <p style="font-size:24px;">/</p>
      </div>
      <div class="controls col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" value="" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-control">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
      <label class="reg-form-left">Postal code/City</label>
      <input type="text" value="" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
       <input type="text" value="" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="register-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Create Account</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```